# Cannot seem to get format of AWS Rekognition right in AWS CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-rekognition

Tried running AWS Rekognition in AWS CLI and got the following error

```
Error parsing parameter '--image': Invalid JSON: Expecting value: line 1 column 48 (char 47)
```

Also tried adjusting the `"` and `'` but got the same error message. Appreciate all the help!

Code as follows:

```
aws rekognition index-faces --image "{\"S3Object\":{\"Bucket\":\"xxx\",\"Name\":"image.PNG"}}" --collection-id "\xxx"\ --detection-attributes \"ALL\" --external-image-id \"xxx\" --region us-west-2
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a command I have successfully used:

```sh
aws rekognition index-faces \
--collection-id Trainers \
--image "S3Object={Bucket=my-bucket,Name=John.jpg}" \
--detection-attributes ALL \
--external-image-id John
```